# How to connect multiple images (very fast)

Tags: java, image

Is there any faster way to connect multiple images than my piece of code?

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = new BufferedImage(64, 64, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
Graphics2D g2 = bufferedImage.createGraphics();

Image image1 = (new ImageIcon(mypath1).getImage();

Image image2 = (new ImageIcon(mypath2).getImage();

Image image3 = (new ImageIcon(mypath3).getImage();

Image image4 = (new ImageIcon(mypath4).getImage();

g2.drawImage(image4, 0, 0, 32, 32, null);
g2.drawImage(image3, 0, 32, 32, 32, null);
g2.drawImage(image2, 32, 0, 32, 32, null);
g2.drawImage(image1, 32, 32, 32, 32, null);

m_placeableIcon = new ImageIcon(bufferedImage);
```

I want to store my bitmaps separate but in JPanel I want to have one solid bitmap/image.

Comment: Do you use image[1,4] elsewhere? If not, you could use `ImageIO` directly to read directly to a `BufferedImage`. It will also be faster if the image "type" of all the images match the BufferedImage you create. That reduces conversion which has to be done by Graphics2D drawing.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.net.URL-

Comment: So I've tested it a lot and unfortunately ImageIO very slow down Graphics2D drawing and the diffrences are very huge, so I decided to stay with ImageIcons :)